# C# WPF Запуск копий приложения в разных доменах (для раздельных cookies)

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser, appdomain

Имеется такая задача:
Есть основное WPF приложение, которое запускает несколько (различное количество) копий другого WPF приложения. Каждая такая копия содержит компонент WebBrowser, на которой выполняется авторизация на сайте http://n.site/
Каждая такая копия должна иметь свою область куки, так как в каждой копии происходит авторизация разных аккаунтов. Как известно, компонент WebBrowser использует "одно пространство куки" для всех запускаемых компонентов.
Я прочитал, что для разделения этого "пространства" требуется запустить копии в разных доменах.

Вопрос: как осуществить это? 
P.S. основное приложение и копии используют одни и те же внешние dll, если это имеет значение. Заранее спасибо.
P.S.S я уже реализовывал подобное в WinForms, и там пространство куки было различно для куки без смены домена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы изменить такое поведение, нужно изменить настройки WinINET с помощью функции InternetSetOption.
Для предотвращения использования WebBrowser'ами запускаемых копий одного и того же приложения общих cookie необходимо изменить настройки WinINET при запуске каждой копии с помощью следующей функции.

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool InternetSetOption(int hInternet, int dwOption, ref int option, int dwBufferLength);

public static void SuppressCommonCookieBehaviour()
    {
        /* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

                INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR (81):
                      A general purpose option that is used to suppress behaviors on a process-wide basis. 
                      The lpBuffer parameter of the function must be a pointer to a DWORD containing the specific behavior to suppress. 
                      This option cannot be queried with InternetQueryOption. 

                INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST (3):
                      Suppresses the persistence of cookies, even if the server has specified them as persistent.
                      Version:  Requires Internet Explorer 8.0 or later.
        */


        int option = 3; /* INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST */

        bool success = InternetSetOption(0, 81 /* INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR */ , ref option, sizeof(int));

        if (!success)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("InternetSetOption() returns false");
    }
```